# gazebo world frame

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I used the gazebo simulation of turbobot3, I encountered a thing that confused me. I used the gmapping algorithm to build a grid map. I found that the location of the odom and map coordinate systems was not in the initial position of the robot. In principle, shouldn't the odom and map coordinate systems be generated at the initial position of the robot?

The following picture describes my problem:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407081/gazebo-world-frame/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perfect odometry with zero slip would yield no difference between odometry and map coordinates, **provided** odometry was initialized to be correct with the map when the robot was started.
When robot comes on it assumes the odometry starts at `(0, 0, 0)` and `(0, 0, 0, 0)` but that isn't where the robot really is, usually.

The correction expression you're looking for is the `map -> odom` transform. It is the correction vectors between map and odom frames.

Related questions with answers:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/401747/publishing-map-odom-transform-using-custom-localization-and-slam-algorithms/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/329980/relationsship-between-map-odom-and-base_link-coordinate-frames/

Good tutorial:

- https://automaticaddison.com/coordinate-frames-and-transforms-for-ros-based-mobile-robots/ (especially **Map to Odom** part)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1